# CSS: How to put button cut in middle flex container

Tags: html, css, sass

Here is a pic from Figma:

[image]

And here is the current page:

[image]

Here is the code:

HTML -

```
<form className={classes['form']} onSubmit={props.submitHandler}>
              <h1 className={classes['form__header']}>Join our website</h1>
              <Input
                placeholder='Username'
                value={props.username}
                changeHandler={props.usernameChangeHandler}
              />
              <Input
                placeholder='Email'
                value={props.email}
                changeHandler={props.emailChangeHandler}
              />
              <Input
                placeholder='Password'
                value={props.password}
                changeHandler={props.passwordChangeHandler}
              />
              <button
                className={classes['form__button']}
                type='submit'>
                Register
              </button>  
            </form>
```

SCSS -

```
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 50vh;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 15px auto;

  &__header {
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #fff;
  }
    
  &__input {
    margin-bottom: 36px;
    padding: 17px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    background-color: map-get($colors, primary);
    border: 4px solid map-get($colors, secondary);
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
        
  &__button {
    transition: all .3s ease;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: map-get($colors, grey);
    background-color: map-get($colors, yellow);
    border-radius: 40px;
    
    &:hover {
      color: #000;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
  }

  &__divider {
    margin: 20px 0;
    align-self: center;
  }
}
```

How can I aling the button like the pic from figma?
..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `position: relative` and the `top`, `left` CSS properties to offset the element from its usual position. Provided that the parent container does not have `overflow: hidden`, the button will be drawn partially outside of the parent container and look as in the picture.

```
...
&__button {
  position: relative;
  top: 48px;
}
...
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.

Comment: In @Brgbegnefneg case, `bottom:-100px` would solve this